# Child constructor arguments from the parent

Tags: ruby

How can a parent get the constructor arguments of a child ?

```
class A
  include Parent

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end
end 

class B
  include Parent

  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end
end 

module Parent

  def print_args
    # here is the code for print args of child, this is not real code
    puts Child.args # this is not real code 
  end  

end
```

The expected behavior would be :

```
a = A.new('hello', 'world')
a.print_args
=> "hello world"

b = B.new('hello')
b.print_args
=> "hello"
```

The Parent module should not now the args names

Comment: `"#{@foo} #{@bar}"`?

Comment: see my updated question

Comment: @Xero Your are now making your question vague. Please learn how module works in Ruby. You should design and teach your classes how they should interact. Code are not magic, but an intention of human to solve something.

Comment: "Please learn how module works" is not a valable answer. I know how it's work. But if I'm missing something, please tell me

Comment: @Xero You seems no idea how it works really, because you are expecting `print_args` should print data of the class while it also should not know any details of those classes who will include them. You are expecting a magic, but it is not a magic. You need to create a dependency. Your `print_args` methods is a abstract method, if you don't want it know the class details, then override it inside the including classes.

Comment: see @ray answer

Comment: @Xero I saw, that is not answer. If you are happy go with it, and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

One way is to have the "children" implement a method that returns their arguments:

```
class A
  include Parent

  def initialize(foo, bar)
    @foo = foo
    @bar = bar
  end

  def args
    [@foo, @bar]
  end
end

class B
  include Parent

  def initialize(foo)
    @foo = foo
  end

  def args
    [@foo]
  end
end
```

The "parent" can than call that method without having to know its implementation:

```
module Parent
  def print_args
    puts args.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Comment: I used `instance_values` instead of defining method `args`. Will it differ for major case or I miss anything?

Comment: @ray `instance_values` is an wildcard, but `args` is not. With `args` you still hold a control which is good.

Comment: @ray what is `instance_values`?

Comment: Yes that method from Rails, and it is a Ruby question.

Answer (score 1):

If your module is included in many classes and you want to display [instance variable](https://apidock.com/rails/v2.1.0/Object/instance_values) values space separated, then you can do as follow,

using only ruby,

```
def print_args
  instance_variables.map { |x| instance_variable_get(x) }.join(' ')
end
```

using rails,

```
def print_args
  instance_values.values.join(' ')
end
```

Comment: This is dangerous because it will take all the instance variables. I think we should stop helping OP as he doesn't seem clear. instead close the question.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I cleared idea before providing code, it will display all instance variables and do not harm (throw error) any other class which will include this module

Comment: That is 100% bad design code. Instead of answering this, Ask OP think [differently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54179634/child-constructor-arguments-from-the-parent/54179699#comment95187955_54179634). And the OP is totally annoying, so I am not interested to teach him any more. He feels he knows everything still he needs to ask. I personally avoid such candidates

Comment: Using `instance_variables` / `instance_values` does remove the argument names from `Parent` as requested by the OP. But it still requires the "children" to be implemented in a very specific way: each argument to `initialize` has to be stored in an instance variable (in the given order) and there must be no other instance variables in order to have this method working. That's very restrictive IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking how to get the *"constructor arguments from the parent"* and since almost everything is possible in Ruby: if you're really adventurous (read: don't do this), you can override the [`new`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Class.html#method-i-new) method upon including `Parent` in order to intercept its arguments and define a singleton method on the instance which prints the argument:

```
module Parent
  def self.included(mod)
    def mod.new(*args)
      super.tap do |instance|
        instance.define_singleton_method(:print_args) do
          puts args.join(' ')
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Example usage:

```
class A
  include Parent

  def initialize(foo, bar)
  end
end

A.new('hello', 'world').print_args
# prints "hello world"
```

The instance doesn't even have to store the arguments in instance variables.